# vs.net multi pre-build commands

Tags: visual-studio, pre-build-event

Hi all I have an external project and I want to build it in the main project for that
I'm using pre-build commands.I want to use multi commands for copying aspx pages and
 ascx usercontrols to sercontrol folder.
When I use one command it works but when I write both lines it returns error code 1 
and not builds.I tried to put comma between two commands but not worked.

```
copy $(SolutionDir)\WebUI.PlugIn.UrlUsage\*.aspx $(ProjectDir)\Pages\Report
copy $(SolutionDir)\WebUI.PlugIn.UrlUsage\*.ascx $(ProjectDir)\UserControls\Report
```

Can you say how to run mlti commands in pre-build events of vs.net?

Answer (score 0):

A good technique is look at the error produced by Visual Studio when the prebuild fails. Copy that error to the command line and run it. That should allow you to see what the issue is more clearly.

In this case it might be something simple like not having quotes round stuff.

It shouldn't make a difference but you don't need the first \ after the $(SolutionDir).